# Adding <jdoc:include calls in Component Templates

Tags: joomla

I'm integrating a component template for a customer. He is using custom templates for com_user / login & reset views.

His site is also using a lot of modules. How can I activate these modules for the component in total, instead of a menu item?

In the module template (`user/login/tmpl/default.php`) I wrote: `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="ja-news" />`, which doesn't work.

Thanks for any answers!

BR,
Sebastian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution in http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=231&t=247191

```
          <?php
          $zone = "ja-news";
          $modules =& JModuleHelper::getModules($zone);
          foreach ($modules as $module){
             echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
          }
          ?>
```

I guess it would be good to have `<jdoc:include` with an additional force="true" parameter..